# Error in logging in authentication against Active Directory with ASP.NET Core by LDAP

Tags: asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap

I'm implementing an ASP.NET Core project and I'm trying to authenticate the user login via LDAP to Active Directory. I'm using this link
https://www.brechtbaekelandt.net/blog/post/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-aspnet-core-2-and-managing-users

in order to implement the authentication against Active Directory with ASP.NET Core. What I've tried in `appsettings.json` is like below:

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "CSDDashboardContext": "Server=xxxx;Database=CSS;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },

  "LdapSettings": {
    "ServerName": "par.fr", 
    "ServerPort": 389, 
    "UseSSL": false,
    "Credentials": {
      "DomainUserName": "par\\koli-h",
      "Password": "asdq/1998"
    },
    "SearchBase": "CN=Users,DC=par,DC=fr",
    "ContainerName": "CN=Users,DC=par,DC=fr", 
    "DomainName": "par.fr",
    "DomainDistinguishedName": "DC=par,DC=fr",
    "SearchProperty": "samAccountName" //????
  }
}
```

Now my problem is after running the project and entering the user: koli-h and pass: asdq/1998 the system shows me invalid username or password. My real username and password in the server are koli-h and asdq/1998. However, if I change my user in the code to for example koli-ha (adding a character in order to make the username incorrect) after running the project, the system shows me an error

> Invalid Credentials

I appreciate if anyone could suggest me what is the problem that I can't log into the system.

Comment: I'd try to use the `System.DirectoryServices` nuget package in version 4.7 - it **does** support .NET Standard 2.0 which allows it to run in a .NET Core app (contrary to what this gentleman claims). Check it out: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices/4.7.0

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'm implementing my project in .net core 3.1. Does your suggestion comply with it. And if I use your mentioned package, How should implement the authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what is stated in that blog post you referenced (which is 2 years old), the `System.DirectoryServices` and `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace **are** in fact supported on .NETStandard 2.0 and thus usable in .NET Core 2.x/3.x.

Check out the relevant Nuget page:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/4.7.0

And thus, you can very easily use the "usual" code to validate user credentials:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

// set up domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "par"))
{
    // validate the user's credentials
    if (ctx.ValidateCredentials(userName, password)
    {
        // credentials are OK --> allow user in
    }
    else
    {
        // credentials aren't OK --> send back error message
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I’m amateur in active directory and ldap concept. So where should I paste this code in my project?

Comment: Excuse me, does DirectoryServices support ldap?

Comment: Yes of course - `DIrectoryServices` is designed to access Active Directory via LDAP

Comment: Could you please tell me an example of how to setup domain context?

Comment: See in my response - the `PrincipalContext` I'm using **is** using a domain setup - for a domain called "par" ..... what more do you need?

Comment: And in appsetting I should paste the similar code I wrote like specifying port number snd server name, ...? I mean how should I specify those setting?

Comment: Yes, you can put the domain name into your config and read it from there.....

Comment: I used your code for authenticating user to Active directory but after entering my correct username and password, and login to the system, it shows me the following error:   An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
LdapException: The LDAP server is unavailable.

System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
PrincipalServerDownException: The server could not be contacted.

System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(string serverName, ref ServerProperties properties)     I appreciate if you suggest me a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your help. The problem was I should specify "mydomain.com" in new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "par")) for example par.com.